# Normality of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Here an exercise from Albert Wilansky:

A space is normal if it is the union of subsets, each of which is open, closed, and normal.

The difficulty that I encounter is that the union is not necessary disjoint.

Comment: For finite and even countable unions this is obvious, because we can make the union disjoint (do you see how?). Is it even true for general unions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a cardinality restriction, or the restriction that the union is disjoint:

Let $X$ be the rational sequence topology on the reals, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_sequence_topology).

It is well known that $X$ is Tychonov, zero-dimensional but not normal (e.g. Jones' lemma will show non-normality).

But $X$ is the union of all $U_n(x)$ (in the Wikipedia notation) and all singletons $\{x\}, x \in \mathbb{Q}$. All of these are compact Hausdorff so normal, and basic open sets as well. But their union $X$ is not normal.

For unions up to countable (so including finite), we can replace $C_n$ by $C_n \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i$ to get disjoint closed and open normal sets in the union, and for this case it's indeed not too hard to show, as you yourself suggest.

Comment: for the countable case, the classical method in real analysis as you suggested will work. I am appreciated that you have pointed out a counterexample for general union, but can you show me the necessary and sufficient conditions for general union?

Comment: I don't know if they exist. It might be the case (I'd have to check) that a locally finite union would do as well. I have difficulty to see what a necessary condition would have to be.